# WinRT ListView and ExpanderView issues

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

After, what I thought was a successful porting of Windows Phone toolkit ExpanderView to WinRT, I noticed that it not working 100% as it should.

Here is what i'm trying to do:-

I have a ListView with the ItemsSource being databound, inside the ItemTemplate of this ListView there is a ExpanderView which I port???!!! The idea is that, I want the expander view to expand when I tap on the ListView item.

This per say, is happening BUT when the ExpanderView expands, it overlap the next ListView item, i.e ListViewItem Height is not changing. Why is that I really don't know. Been trying every possible idea I came up with to solve this but in vain :(

Can anyone helps me and guide me in the right direction?

Below is a link to a simple example (VS project with all the necessary code) to demo the problem
[Simple Universal App to demo the problem](http://1drv.ms/1hCwE71)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I notice in your demo that your `ExpanderView`'s `ItemTemplate` has a base element of a `ListViewItem`. Is there a reason for this? Have you tried it without it?

Comment: @Nate I Think this was a typo. Thanks again

Comment: I don't think it is actually. I checked the WPToolkit code and it was the same there.

Comment: @ajitsunny asks "I am also trying same in code and facing multiple errors. It is taking more memory. Application is crashing after loading around 200+ records in ExpanderView. Can you share your code to ajit.net2 at gmail com, so that I can review that and identify the issue."

Comment: @DreamNet could you provide the final solution? The link in your question is no longer working

Comment: I have ported the ExpanderView with the original sample of toolkit to winrt today [link](https://github.com/AhmedRashad/WpToWinrt)  , I know it's late for you but someone else might need it. I also found another port which belongs to Dreamnet but didn't test it [link](https://expanderview.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few places where you have animations that are making layout changes. These animations are very UI-thread heavy, so require the property `EnableDependentAnimations` to be set to `True`. You can find more out about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx). You will likely need to go into the styles and manually change the VisualStates to make this change. One such example is:

In your ExpanderResource.xaml:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpansionStates">
    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualTransition From="Collapsed"
                          GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="Expanded">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsCanvas" EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.00" Value="0" />
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="CollapsedToExpandedKeyFrame" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="1" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualTransition>
    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Note that the `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` targetting `(FrameworkElement.Height)` requires `EnableDependentAnimations="True"`, as this affects the layout.

This is not the only place in that file that needs to be fixed. Further, I don't think it will solve all of your layout problems. It will get it property expanding the layout though.

Comment: Thanks dude, this have made my day. This property have done the work even if the animation is a bit jarring. Leason learned.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are using a `stackpanel` as your panel.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Sorry this will not help, you can see it in my example that I have this code and it is not working :(

Comment: Oh sry to hear that, is it the project that didn't work or the ExpanderView one? The project one is set very fast so it could be not working, as I didn't raelly tested it as I would love. Anyhow I will re-send the ExpanderView one if that is okay_